# Chromium won't launch on Ubuntu 18.04 - Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported

Tags: 18.04, chromium, 32-bit

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with a 32bit OS. Chromium-browser installed with apt-get (don't know if that's relevant). Chromium version 73.0.3683.86.

When I try to launch chromium-browser without sudo I get a whole lot of permissions errors.

```
[4945:4961:0518/224223.421239:ERROR:cache_util.cc(140)] Unable to move cache folder /home/matti/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/GPUCache to /home/matti/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/old_GPUCache_000
[4945:4961:0518/224223.421277:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[4945:4961:0518/224223.421403:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(622)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[4945:4961:0518/224223.617090:ERROR:cache_util.cc(140)] Unable to move cache folder /home/matti/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/GPUCache to /home/matti/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/old_GPUCache_000
[4945:4961:0518/224223.617192:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[4945:4961:0518/224223.617261:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(622)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801528:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801568:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/matti/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801605:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/matti/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801625:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/matti/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801645:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(433)] readlink failed: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801664:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(256)] readlink(/home/matti/.config/chromium/SingletonLock) failed: Permission denied (13)
[4945:4945:0518/224223.801706:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1422)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Then, running with sudo I get this:

```
[5087:5087:0518/224336.192699:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

Finally running with "--no-sandbox" (as the error suggested) will launch the browser successfully (kind of. It launches, but a few more errors pop up in the terminal).

Needless to say I cannot launch the browser from the application menu, which is what I want. What could be done to fix this? Is anybody else able to use Chromium on Ubuntu 18.04 with 32bit OS?